# Exports within another file, called in the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have two files, **index.js** & **test.js**.

Now they contain the following code;
**index.js**

```
var test = require('./test');

test.execute();

function execute(){
  console.log('Execute this from the test file');
}

module.exports = {
  execute
}
```

**test.js**

```
var index = require('./index'); 

index.execute();

function execute(){
  console.log('Execute this from the index file');
}

module.exports = {
  execute
}
```

They're both pretty much the same thing, all they are doing is executing the opponents `execute()` function. However, when I start node I run `node index` to start the server. Now what happens is the `execute()` function of the test.js file becomes non-existent as the test module is required before the execute function with index.js is exported.

What is a good solution to work around this issue?

Comment: @JoséAntonioPostigo thanks Ill check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in this exact case you can just up the export assigning to the top:

**index.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  execute
}

var test = require('./test');

test.execute();

function execute(){
  console.log('Execute this from the test file');
}
```

**test.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  execute
}

var index = require('./index'); 

index.execute();

function execute(){
  console.log('Execute this from the index file');
}
```